# How to convert CValues to List in Kotlin/Native (or iterate)?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, cinterop

I have a `CValues<VkLayerProperties>` which is passed to a C function so that it can fill the array.

```kotlin
    val layerProperties = createValues<VkLayerProperties>(layerCount.value.toInt()) {}
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(layerCount.ptr, layerProperties.ptr)
```

How do I convert this array to a `List` or how do I iterate over it in Kotlin?